# swift ios app with firebase crashes when stressed

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have made an IOS app in swift, with a firebase backend database. It works fine, as long as I don't stress the app. It is a rather memory and cpu-consuming application.

If I stress the app with rapid commands however, it crashes occasionally.
When the app is loaded, it populates a tableView with data from firebase, and when I go to the mapViewController, it downloads a lot of Lat/Long coordinates, and creatses polylines with an annotation. 
The error I get, is "Fatal error Unecxpectedely found nil while unwrapping an optional".

Now, it only happens sometimes when I stress the app, so my question is:

1:Is it normal that firebase/the app can not handle that amount of data transfer?

2: Would the answer to my problem be to save the data in in file, put it on firebase storage, and afterwards download the file and read the data afterwards.

EDIT: I normally have this error - which is difficult to debug

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1: 
  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
```

but just before I could go down the stack trace, and I found this error

[image]

this is the way it could look in firebase
[image]

Comment: If the application crash message is _Fatal error Unecxpectedely found nil while unwrapping an optional_, then the crash is not due to "stress" on the app (you should check if any memory leaks are present though.) Maybe you're assuming something is not `nil` and you're executing a forced unwarp. If you provide the code causing the crash then maybe we'll be able to track down the issue. Check the stacktrace, breakpoints are helpful too.

Comment: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional" typically points to a coding error. It only happening in certain situations may point to a race condition. But it's hard to say anything more concrete without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't force unwrap then. Use `if let` syntax. It's there for a reason.

Comment: The bigger question here is why are you populating a class var (self?.positions) and then also passing that class var to the completion handler? Also, (self?.positions)! force unwraps *positions*, and if it's nil, that would cause the error as well. So for example; if *snapshot.exists* is false, that var would not be populated and could be nil, then it's unwrapped causing the error.